# convert less to pure css or using less javascript library

Tags: css, less

I just started using css less and thinking about which way is better: include less file to page with less.js library or convert less into pure css and include that file to a page.

Which way do you use and think which way is better?

Comment: I would suggest instead of using .js file which convert LESS file into CSS use this online tool which will convert `LESS code` into `CSS`. http://less2css.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would compile the less to css and implement the compiled file to my site.
 I think this is the usual way to do this.

There are a lot of tools for this task. Take a look at [compass](http://compass-style.org/) and/or [scout](http://mhs.github.io/scout-app/).
Compiling process can also do with commmand line itself or [Gruntjs](https://www.google.de/search?q=gruntjs%20less&oq=gruntjs%20less&aqs=chrome..69i57j0j69i60l2j0l2.4383j0j1&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#q=grunt%20js%20less&spell=1). 
All of these tool compiling the less files onthefly.